# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window - Integrating Javascript Library in Swift

Tags: javascript, swift

I am integrating a custom Javascript Library in my Swift app, the js file contains reference to window object in multiple places, and when loading the file using ``JavascriptCore its throwing me this error.
`ReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: window"`

How do I get rid of this error, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The window object is a DOM container so it suppose to be used in a browser. Here is the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window?retiredLocale=it

Since I'm not a swift expert I can't give to you a technical response but reading the question I suppose that you are loading a javascript engine (like V8) and not a webview so the DOM doesn't exist and then the window object dosn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I am not loading a webview. I am using JavascriptCore engine to load my js files. it would be great if I can avoid that reference to window, otherwise I wouldn't be able to use the library itself in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using a npm package in swift with `JavaScriptCore`. I managed to get a bundled version of the package (for example `dummy.bundle.js`).

I then opened the bundled file and added the following:

```js
var window = {}
// rest of the bundled file goes here
```

That fixed the issue for me, but it has a big caveat. If the library you're trying to get to work uses some DOM API (e.g. `window.location`), that'll probably throw an error as well. You can start by defining `window` and bit by bit defining (or [polyfilling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill)) the APIs needed by your library.